# Laravel Storing BIgInt in Session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm trying to store some user related information in a Session and it works out just fine when the user doesn't have a bigInteger id, but when they do it simply doesn't work out well.

When I use dd(); in a route located in web.php (GET Request) the id shows up just fine, but when I try to dd(); it out somewhere else it simply returns null.

For example I have a button that says "Link Account" when the user is not logged in and it's supposed to say "Logout" when the session is available.

Also I forward the user into a specific page that is only accessible by logged in users (users that have session data stored) and it enters the page without an issue, but after that redirection the user cannot go to any other page that's restricted to non-logged users.

I'm suspecting that it's related to the integer type, since all the other users do not have a single issue on performing any operations whatsoever.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

The Procedure more or less looks like this.

Storing the ID in a Controller:

```
$userId = 221345230; // The number looks like that x)
Session::put('userId', $userId);
```

Checking the ID in a middleware:

```
if(!session('userId')){
   return redirect("/");
}
```

Checking the ID in a view:

```
@if(!session('userId'))
 <a>Link Account</a>
@else
 <a>Logout</a>
```

Comment: can you show what you are doing? its just an integer to PHP

Comment: I've added some example code I hope it'll help

Comment: sounds like you don't have a valid session any more, either its being flushed or you have a new session for that request

Comment: Yes, all routes that are getting GET REQUESTS are under web.php

Comment: We have another file for POST requests which is stored under the same folder routes. Also just a reminder that it works out just fine when the user is not one of the bigInteger users.

Comment: Yeah the problem is not in the type then, though only the users whom have that kind of a bigInteger have this issue. These bigIntegers used to transform to negative integers in the database, but I've fixed that issue which was related to the database column type not being BIGINT, but after I made that change this issue started appearing, note that now we're storing the users without any issues, no negative numbers etc.

Comment: not sure where the id comes from but i would dump that `$userId` to make sure it is the value you think it is

Comment: im gonna clean up my comments since i am not really sure the issue atm without more information, don't want have these comments filled, too much reading for other people :)

Comment: Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had not changed the types inside the User Model.

Meaning while making a request to get the user data from the database the model was sending an integer and not a string, which will not succeed when you're working with BIGINT in MySQL.

So make sure you change your types everywhere needed guys :D

Example

```
// Wrong
$user_id = 222234312432;
User::where("user_id", $user_id);

// Correct
$user_id = (string) 222234312432;
User::where("user_id", $user_id);
```